# Image will not center at screen width bigger than 1355px on responsive website

Tags: html, css

Image centered when screen is less than 1355px

[image]

Image not centered when screen size is more than 1355px
[image]

```
.nav {  
    font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    color:#FFB8B8;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.one img {
    height: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:right;` in your CSS. When the screen size is more than 1355px in your case the navigation bar has enough space to fit itself on the right and the Image beside it. This happens when float is used. If you want to still keep the navigation bar on the right side of the page you can add a `margin-left` of whatever fits right with your page to keep the navigation bar all the way to the right. If you still do not like this method then you can also use the `position:` CSS attribute to position the navigation bar exactly where you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you. Removing the `float: right` does solve the image issue. However, now the `margin-left`applied to the nav makes it so it doesn't scale down with the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with specifying a fixed height for the navigation, doing as the code below should work for you:

```css
.parent {
  height:98px;
  display:block;
}

.nav {  
  font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  color:#FFB8B8;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: black;
}

.img{
  background:yellow;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="nav">
    nav
  </div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  image
</div>
```

In summary, I added a parent with a fixed height and display as block. The parent will contain the navigation. I also made img position as relative instead of height as relative.

Happy coding,